# Responsive layout background in Android (Vector)

Tags: android, layout, background, responsive, nine-patch

I need to change background my layouts to something like a folder ( see attachment), and I need it to be vector, so folder name tag be always in same size. I can't use 9 patch since I need it to be vector.

[image]

Comment: I see no reason why you cannot use nine patch drawables

Comment: Yes, my mistake, now edited question.

Comment: sorry you cannot do such thing with vector